# What does the "stop" command in dovecot sieve do?

Tags: sieve

There's a command in the rules file called `stop`, which stops processing. I'm not sure why this is needed though. If it's the last command in a list of directives within a rule, then isn't the rule already done processing? Or does it mean don't skip to the next rule in the list? In other words, let's say my sieve file has a list of rules:

```
Rule A
Rule B
Rule C
Rule D
```

If Rule B has a `stop` command at the end, will rules C and D be skipped? And I'm assuming rules are executed in the order they appear in the sieve file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if rule B contains the `stop` command at the end, rules C and D will be skipped.

> The "stop" action ends all processing.  If the implicit keep has not been cancelled, then it is taken.
> — [RFC 5228 section 3.3 "Control stop"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5228#section-3.3)

---

This is useful when detecting spam and a using a vacation message or some `fileinto` rules. You can `discard` the spam followed by `stop` which skips all following rules meaning you are not going to reply to them via your vacation rule and they will not be put in another mailbox via fileinto rules.

If you are using `if` and `elsif` you can avoid this problem.